# How to find distance between midpoint and farthest corner after rotate?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

i have a box whose width, height and angle sizes are dynamic. so I need to know the distance(red line) between the midpoint before rotated (black color), and the farthest corner after turning(blue color).
its posible to khow distance(red line) base on angle, width and height?
I've tried but didn't find a solution. thank you for responding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hi, have a look on the above figure. If $d$ is the distance you want to get, then:

$d=\frac{H}{2}+\overline{CB}$. By analysing the triangle $ABC$, you have:

$\sin \theta = \frac{\overline{CB}}{\overline{AB}}=\frac{\overline{CB}}{W/2}$. Thus:

$d=\frac{H}{2}+\frac{W}{2}\sin \theta$